# MySQL - The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, debian, debian-wheezy, mysql5, mysql5.5

I have installed MySQL 5.6.16 on Debain 7.4.

But i encountered problems with starting mysql, where every time i start mysql i get this error:

```
The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid). ... failed!
```

After a lot of googling i saw that i should rename/move **my.cnf** file from **/etc/mysql** to see if mysql starts. And it start and stop without problems, but if try to connect to database with my software i get this:

```
Caught database OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

Then i tried adding/deleting everything from /var/run/mysqld and adding users and groups but nothing changes.

And i can't find any log files from mysql even setting them up in my.cnf.

This is my.cnf file from /etc/mysql [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/unhNF0v5)

Comment: How you installed Mysql on yuor Debian via apt-get or you compiled it?

Comment: @AbhishekAnandAmralkar i complied it.

Comment: Launch the start script in debug mode and see where/why it fails. bash -x /etc/init.d/mysql start

Comment: This is what i get in ouput: http://pastebin.com/DDw3VzNv

Comment: Solved by installing 5.5 from debian repository. I think there is a bug in 5.6.16

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem. In my case, it was a missing PID file. So I had to manually kill the MySQL process and then restart it. The PID file was then created when I restarted MySQL.

Here's a great post that may help you:
http://linuxadministrator.pro/blog/?p=225